# Depurando Lua embebido en C++

Tags: c++, embebido, lua

Estoy probando a integrar [Lua](https://www.lua.org) con **C++** y me encuentro con algunas dudas a la hora de depurar los errores.

Cuando falla alguna parte de un script lua, ya sea un error en tiempo de ejecución o un error de sintaxis, Lua le devuelve el control al programa anfitrión de forma bastante silenciosa. Básicamente `luaL_dofile` termina devolviendo `1`.

Por lo que he estado leyendo en la [referencia oficial](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-debug.getinfo), cuando sucede un error Lua rellena la estructura `lua_Debug` con información más detallada si llamamos a la función `lua_getinfo`... o eso me ha parecido entender. :-(

Por un lado tengo una intuición sobre el procedimiento de obtener más información para depurar errores, pero en la práctica... no va.

Pego aquí el código de main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GetHttp.h"
#include "Conf.h"
#include "App.h"
#include "Poco/Logger.h"

extern "C"
{
  #include "lua5.2/lua.h"
  #include "lua5.2/lualib.h"
  #include "lua5.2/lauxlib.h"
}

#include <luabind/luabind.hpp>
#include <luabind/out_value_policy.hpp>
#include <luabind/adopt_policy.hpp>
#include <luabind/return_reference_to_policy.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Conf conf;

  GetHttp ini;
  ini.setConf(&conf);

  conf.logger.information("- Iniciando :-D");
  const char file[]="mods/test.lua";
  lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
  conf.logger.information("Leido lua_state");

  luaL_openlibs(L);
  conf.logger.information("Leido openlibs");

  luabind::open(L);
  conf.logger.information("Abierto luabind");

  luabind::module(L)
        [
                luabind::class_<GetHttp>("GetHttp")
                        .def(luabind::constructor<>())
                        .def("Get",&GetHttp::miGet)
        ];
 conf.logger.information("Cargado módulo");

 int retorno = luaL_dofile(L,file);
 lua_close(L);
 if(retorno == 0)
 {
        conf.logger.information("Saliendo...");
 }
 else
 {
        cout << "Saliendo con errores" << endl;
        conf.logger.information("Saliendo... con errores");
        lua_Debug ar;
        lua_getglobal(L, "extraerTelefonos"); 
        lua_getinfo(L, ">Sn", &ar);
        cout << "-- " << ar.what << endl;
        cout << "-- " << ar.source << endl;
        cout << "-- " << ar.linedefined << endl;
        cout << "-- " << ar.name << endl;
        cout << "-- " << ar.namewhat << endl;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

El segundo argumento de `lua_getglobal` pongo el nombre de la función que creo que está provocando el fallo... pero no se si el segundo parámetro vale exactamente para eso.

Como puede observar al terminar el progroma sólo hay basura en `lua_Debug`.

Salida del programa:

```
Encontradas 30 coincidencias 
Saliendo con errores
-- C
-- =[C]
-- -1
-- %
```

**¿Cómo tengo que hacer para obtener información sobre los errores de un script Lua dentro de un programa C++?**

**¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?**

Comment: No tengo LUA pero... ¿Has probado a postponer la llamada a `lua_close` hasta después del `if-else`? Ignoro las labores de limpieza que realiza pero puede que borre los datos a recuperar a través de `lua_getinfo`

Comment: Pues efectivamente. Madre mía que despiste XDDD. Muchas gracias @eferion

Comment: Perfecto, he añadido una respuesta para que sirva como referencia a futuros visitantes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lua_close(L); // <<---
if(retorno == 0)
{
  // ...
}
else
{
  cout << "Saliendo con errores" << endl;
  conf.logger.information("Saliendo... con errores");
  lua_Debug ar;
  lua_getglobal(L, "extraerTelefonos"); 
  lua_getinfo(L, ">Sn", &ar);
  cout << "-- " << ar.what << endl;
  cout << "-- " << ar.source << endl;
  cout << "-- " << ar.linedefined << endl;
  cout << "-- " << ar.name << endl;
  cout << "-- " << ar.namewhat << endl;
}
```

Mueve la línea indicada al final del `if-else`. `lua_close` libera los recursos relacionados con el script, entre ellos se encuentran los datos recuperables por `lua_getinfo`.

Debería quedar así:

```
if(retorno == 0)
{
  // ...
}
else
{
  cout << "Saliendo con errores" << endl;
  conf.logger.information("Saliendo... con errores");
  lua_Debug ar;
  lua_getglobal(L, "extraerTelefonos"); 
  lua_getinfo(L, ">Sn", &ar);
  cout << "-- " << ar.what << endl;
  cout << "-- " << ar.source << endl;
  cout << "-- " << ar.linedefined << endl;
  cout << "-- " << ar.name << endl;
  cout << "-- " << ar.namewhat << endl;
}
lua_close(L);
```